# No path in vim tabline

Tags: vim

Is there any way to remove the path at the beginning of the vim tabline so that it just displays the filename?

I saw some similar posts, but none that really worked for me. The following solution works for the airline plugin but I'm not using that plugin.

`let g:airline#extensions#tabline#fnamemod = ':t'`

Comment: See `:help setting-tabline`.

Comment: I had already looked at that and didn't know what to do with their example. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Also see `:h fnamemodify()`, specifically the `:t` option